# C++ protected declaration in constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, declaration, protected

I am trying to understand what the following code is doing and why:

```
class Beverage {
    std::string m_description;
protected:
    Beverage(std::string aDescription):m_description(aDescription){}
```

The part I am trying to understand is the ":m_description(aDescription){}" I don't understand what that is declaring.

Code from [Olivianeacsu](https://github.com/Olivianeacsu/DecoratorPattern/blob/master/src/Beverage.h)

Comment: @NathanOliver, shall we reopen on the grounds that a good answer should mention the protected constructor?

Comment: @Bathsheba I think that is tangential.  the OP specifically states they do not understand the `:m_description(aDescription){}` part.

Answer (score 1):

`:m_description(aDescription)` is initialising the member `m_description`.

This is preferred to writing `m_description = aDescription` in the constructor body, as for one thing, `m_description` can then be `const` and that member type does not require a default constructor.

The fact that the constructor is `protected` means that it can only be called from base classes. The compiler will also not generate a *default* constructor in this instance, so this means that `Beverage` **must** be inherited.